# What does "~" in front of a function name inside a class mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I added a class using the 'add class' item in Visual Studio Express and it generated two functions in the .cpp file with the same names. But the second has the `~` character in front of it.

What does it mean?

Comment: Flagging this as offtopic since it has nothing to do with game development, it's a basic C++ question.

Comment: This question should be migrated to StackOverflow.

Comment: This question should simply be deleted. Or closed as a duplicate of any beginner book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One without `~` in front of the name is a constructor and one with `~` in front of it's name is a destructor.

This however only applies if the function name matches exactly the class name. Otherwise it would not represent a constructor or destructor and the character `~` would most likely result in a syntax error.

[Check this tutorial on constructors and destructors.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm)

Comment: This is only correct if that "function name" matches exactly the class name, otherwise it would result in a syntax error since it would not be a constructor/destructor (which by rule have to be the class names)!

Answer (score 1):

C++ has the concept of constructors and destructors.

A constructor is a method that is executed once a class instance is created. It is named with the same name as the class, but with no return type. The constructor is usually where you initialize member variables of a class.

A destructor, as the name implies, is executed once a class instance is destroyed. It is the place to do any non-automatic cleanup, such as closing files, database connections, etc. A destructor is also named with the same name as the class, no return type, but with a tilde `~` at the beginning. You don't need to define a destructor for every class. It can be omitted if no manual cleanup is required.

See this example, and [test it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3f5ada3a8ac2690), to get a better grasp of it:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {

public:

    // Constructor declaration
    MyClass()
    {
        std::cout << "on MyClass constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    // Destructor declaration
    ~MyClass()
    {
        std::cout << "on MyClass destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClassInstance;
}
```